# how to show the html content using onload javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a login form using html,css and javascript and it works properly. But the problem is, it did not show my html content and it only show the username name on the other page. Can anyone please help me? i want the target.html page has show my html content and also the username.

index.html

```
 <html> 
  <head>
  <title>Login page</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align="center";font-size:20pt;
      color:#00FF00;>
     Simple Login Page
    </h1>
    <form name="myform">
    Username<input type="text" name="userid" id="userid"/>
    Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
     </form>

      <script language="javascript">

     function check(form)
     {

     if(form.userid.value && form.pswrd.value)
     {
      window.location="target.html"
   alert("Welcome to this page")
   var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
      }
     else
      {

     alert("Error Password or Username")
    }
   }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

target.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Login page</title>
 <style>
 h1.text{
 color: red;
 }
 </style>
 <script>
 function init(){
 var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");

document.write("Welcome "+userid);
}
  window.onload=init;
</script>

 <body>
<h1 class="text">Simple Login Page</h1> 
<a href="confirm.html">Confirm.html</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: You have multiple issues. The worst is the document.write. The other is that you can do nothing on the current page after a location change

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.write` in onload will cause the content to be wiped.

`document.write` is generally considered bad, so don't use it.

[More on `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

Answer (score 0):

document.write writes to the page and overwrites any existing html. What you're trying to do it append something to the page. Which means you can do putting in a placeholder and then filling it with your data. Also on your index.html page you have a lot of code that wont execute because you've already changed locations. The most important is the localStorage.setItem("userid", userid); It needs to move above your location reset for your target.html to work.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Login page</title>
 <style>
 h1.text{
 color: red;
 }
 </style>
 <script>
 function init(){
 var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");

document.getElementById("username").innerHTML("Welcome "+userid);
}
  window.onload=init;
</script>

 <body>
<span id='username'></span>
<h1 class="text">Simple Login Page</h1> 
<a href="confirm.html">Confirm.html</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by putting in a placeholder and then filling it with your data. Importantly, what is a placeholder and what data should i add in. Also, where is the location reset?